# Javascript / Nodejs check if something is bigint type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, int, biginteger, bigint

Is there a way to check if something is `bigint` type?

I would like to check this:

`99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`

I know this number can't be represented as an Integer. How can I check if it can be represented as a bigint?

If I use the `typeof` on it, it says `number`.

Also is there any way to specify a type with a decimal at the end?

example: `99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.99`

Comment: Check if it's larger than the maximum Integer amount?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 1):

You can use Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER to check if is a bigint or not. Link below:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

or a better way: Number.isSafeInteger()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger